# C# String EPPLUS

Tags: c#, directory, epplus

I cant seem to get the file to save in the folder with a "," in it.

```
string myDir = @"S:\\Shared\\SFD\\SFD Analysis\\2016-12-30, Collab Care\\";
```

...`xls.Save();`

Any thoughts. I used a literal string, which fixed the spaces, but I would like to reference Windows Filenames with "," in them? Thanks

Comment: `"S:\\Shared\\SFD\\\"SFD Analysis\"\\\"2016-12-30, Collab Care\"\\"`

Comment: Are you getting an error? What does the result look like?

Comment: You're using the literal operator @ but escaping your path delimiter \ - choose one or the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the verbatim string literal operator @ *and* escaping the path delimiter

```
string myDir = @"S:\\Shared\\SFD\\SFD Analysis\\2016-12-30, Collab Care\\";
```

Try either

```
string myDir = @"S:\Shared\SFD\SFD Analysis\2016-12-30, Collab Care\";
```

or

```
string myDir = "S:\\Shared\\SFD\\SFD Analysis\\2016-12-30, Collab Care\\";
```